# How to solder SMDs on metal core PCB?

Tags: led, pcb, soldering

I have a bit of soldering experience but look for instructions on how to solder on an aluminum core PCB. The PCB is for high power LEDs that dissipate a lot of great, hence the metal core. The components are LED drivers, resistors, capacitors and alike for a simple LED board.

The board cools so efficiently that soldering is near impossible. I tried preheating the board on a Crepe maker (cheap hot plate). It either was too cold and I still couldn't solder or too hot so the LED lenses we melting. I'm looking for and tips or experiences to send me in the right direction.

Comment: It needs a controlled temp hot plate following the recommended thermal profile. WHat do you have with this power level> Stove top?

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/zjTna.png  What do you have to measure surface temp?

Comment: Exactly as Sunnyskyguy says: you need to find the middle, where it's hot enough but not too hot; also, might be a matter of using solder paste instead of solder "wire".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A good DIY method for the occasional "home reflow solderer" is the electric frying pan technique. It allows you to heat the MCPCB very evenly. Almost any $19,99 model from a thrift shop will do the trick.

First, clean the MCPCB with Isopropyl alcohol. Apply a bit of flux with a flux pen. Then squirt a minute bead of solder paste, use one that already comes syringed, on the anode, cathode and heat-sink contacts of the MCPCB. Next place your LED in the right location. Turn on the electric frying plan until the solder paste liquifies. You will see that the surface tension will suck your LED in the right location.

With this technique, you can even "home-reflow" intimidating looking DFN ICs and the like surprisingly accurately. Sparkfun et al. have good examples of this in their old video library [here](https://www.sparkfun.com/tutorials/59#Skillet).